holidaymakers of one region
The sentence below is from this site. Is the preposition "of" correct here? If it is correct, does it mean that those holidaymakers are from another region and they traveled to the region mentioned in sentence to go on holiday?

The charts show the proportion of holidaymakers of one region staying
in different types of accommodation in three different years.


Why wouldn't it be right? That is an English-teaching site.

We usually speak of holidaymakers from Britain rather than ...of Britain, but both prepositions are "valid". The less common version might be less "marked" in contexts in contrived contexts like quirky slogans: Holidaymakers of Britain unite! You have nothing to lose but your passports!

So, those holidaymakers are actually from the region mentioned in the sentence? I thought they went to that region for holidays.

The sentence implies taking holiday away, but not necessarily. To be fair, the comparison uses a single region, rather than showing that New Yorkers like fancy hotels and farmers stay with family.

Both sample answers refer to 'holidaymakers from a region', so presumably that is the intended meaning. If it was about people taking holidays in a particular region, in would have been used.

I think you are right to question that preposition.  I don't find the phrase "holidaymakers of one region" perfectly idiomatic if the intended  meaning  of of is "coming from" a particular place. Indeed, in the body of the article the author changes to "from a region".

We use the preposition to with the place being visited:  Canadian vacationers to Florida.

The charts show the proportion of holidaymakers of one region staying in different types of accommodation in three different years.
I believe you find your answer in the first sentence of Sample Answer 1:

The pie charts compare the ratio of holidaymakers from a region who used different types of lodging in 1965, 1985 and 2005.

Or in the first sentence of Sample Answer 2:

The pie charts outline the percentages of holidaymakers from a particular region...

However, it's a terrible example because:

It introduces the notion of a "region" that is not contained anywhere in the pie charts.
It's redundant because the assumption would be that a holidaymaker can only be from one region.

On a side note, pie charts are a terrible way of communicating information about data, especially when you're trying to make comparisons across years. It's much more clear to use a bar chart for a single year:

and especially for more than one year:

